# How can I get multiple 'paragraph' components to display in this ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

We're using angular.js (Angular 1.2) for the basis of a component-based set of e-learning templates. It all works well, but there's a slight bug I've noticed:

We have a slick-based carousel component whose slides can contain sub-components (paragraphs, bullet lists, images etc). The trouble is, if you want to add more than one paragraph, only the last paragraph is added. Here's the html for the carousel component:

```
<div slick infinite=true slides-to-show=1 slides-to-scroll=1 dots=true lazy-load='ondemand' fade={{component.carousel.fade}} adaptive-height=true class="caro">  
 <!--[if !IE 8]>
 <style type="text/css">.slick-dots{display:none;}
 </style>
<![endif]-->
    <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="component in component.carousel.carousel_components"></div>


    <div>
        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(innerIndex,component) in component.inner_components"></div>



            <div ng-class="getStyle(component.desktop_width,'md') + ' ' + getStyle(component.tablet_width,'sm') + ' ' +  getStyle(component.mobile_width,'xs')">

                <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(innerType, object) in component"></div>


                    <div ng-attr-id="{{'page-' + pageId + '-section-' + (skey+1) + '-column-' + ckey + '-' + type + '-'+ index+ '-' + innerType + '-'+ innerIndex}}" ng-switch="innerType">
                        <div ng-switch-when="image" eng-image></div>
                        <div class="caro_comp" ng-switch-when="paragraph" eng-paragraph></div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="video" eng-video></div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="bullet" eng-bullet></div>
                        <div class="caro_comp" ng-switch-when="bullet_list" eng-bullet-list></div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="popup" eng-popup></div>
                        <div class="caro_comp" ng-switch-when="inject" eng-inject></div>
                    </div>

                <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>

            </div>

        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

The important part is the section between ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

And here is some example json, which provides the content for the carousel, which features 2 paragraph components on the first slide of the carousel:

```
"carousel": {
   "carousel_components": [
       {
           "inner_components": [
              {
                  "desktop_width":"0.5",
                  "paragraph": {
                       "text": "Placeholder text."
                  },
                  "paragraph": {
                       "text": "Only this second paragraph displays."
                  }
              },
              {
                  "desktop_width":"0.5",
                  "image": {                                                
                      "alt_name": "placeholder",
                      "src": "assets/images/page2_carousel1_01.png"
                  }
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "inner_components": [
              {
                  "desktop_width":"0.5",
                  "paragraph": {
                      "text": "Second example slide with one paragraph."
                  }
              },
              {
                  "desktop_width":"0.5",
                  "image": {                                                
                      "alt_name": "placeholder",
                      "src": "assets/images/page2_carousel1_02.png"
                  }
              }
          ]
       }                                               
    ]
 }
```

Is there something in the syntax of the carousel ng-repeat code that is preventing more than one paragraph component from being added by angular?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your problem is in your data.  Whenever a object contains more than 1 property with the same name, it always takes the last one.  The next one overwrites the previous 1.

Comment: Sorry, missed a bit.  In this case, "paragraph" is overwritten with only the one that is displaying.

Comment: Ah ha! I see! This was handed to me as is, so I've added another level to the json hierarchy; a 'column' element. The columns have the 'desktop_width' property and a list of inner_components. Seems to work now, thanks. Feel free to add your comment as an answer, if you want...